# How to make difference between menu and dropdown submenu with CSS3

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I got some problem with submenu, all I want is to have different color of submenu when his parent is clicked, but i don't want the submenu inherits .active class styling from parent like it's in my code. Currently submenu get all grey when parent "Usluge" is clicked and it need to be dark blue. On hover it acts normal, like it should. Anybody can help?

Here is the HTML:

```
            <header class="topheader">
            <nav>
                <div class="nav-btn"></div>
                <ul class="navi">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Početna</a></li>
                    <li><a href="o_nama.html">O nama</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ordinacija.html">Ordinacija</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="usluge.html">Usluge</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="usluge.html">Restaurativna dentalna medicina</a></li>
                            <li><a href="usluga2.html">Estetska dentalna medicina</a></li>
                            <li><a href="usluga3.html">Dječja dentalna medicina</a></li>
                            <li><a href="usluga4.html">Endodoncija</a></li>
                            <li><a href="usluga5.html">Dentalna protetika</a></li>
                            <li><a href="usluga6.html">Oralna kirurgija</a></li>
                            <li><a href="usluga7.html">Parodontologija</a></li>
                            <li><a href="usluga8.html">Rendgen</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </header>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 /*---MENU---*/
.topheader a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
}

.topheader nav{
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:169px;
    width:490px;
    padding:0;
}

.topheader nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
}

.topheader nav ul li{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.topheader ul li a:link, .topheader ul li a:visited{
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 17px 20px;
    font-size: 110%;
    height: 16px;
}

.topheader nav a:hover, .topheader nav a:active, .topheader ul .active a:link{
    background-color: #aeadad;
    text-shadow: none;
}

/*---SUBMENU---*/
.topheader ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    display:block;
    z-index:10000;
}

.topheader ul li ul li{
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:150px;
}

.topheader ul li ul li a{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:130px;
    background-color: #01415a;
    border-top: 1px solid #7bc4f1;
}

.topheader ul li ul a:link, .topheader ul li ul a:visited{
    color: #FFF;
    display:table-cell;
    padding:15px 15px;
    font-size: 105%;
}

.topheader ul li ul li:hover, .topheader ul li ul a:hover{
    background-color: #68a2ba;
}

.topheader ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;
}

.topheader nav ul li a:active .topheader nav ul li ul li a{
   background-color: #01415a;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct your css concept....

Below is some example link's  that will help you to clear your dropdown menu concept...

1) [First Link](http://csswizardry.com/demos/css-dropdown/)

2) [Second Link](http://www.menucool.com/horizontal/drop-down-menu)

3) [Third Link](http://cssmenumaker.com/css-drop-down-menu)

These link contain a different style's of dropdown menu, which is very easy to understand if you have some of the basic css concept...

Comment: if this is what you are looking for then accept this as your answer, or the links above is helpful then vote the answer as helpful....